# Deserializing .NET Dictionary using ISerializable

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, serialization

I have problems getting de-/serialization of a Dictionary working when implementing ISerializable in the enclosing class. It seems to be able to automatically de-/serialize if I just apply the SerializableAttribute. I need to check the deserialized Dictionary in the process however, so I need ISerializable to be working.

I set up a little test to be sure it wasn't due to some other problems. The **Test** class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
class Test : ISerializable
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _dict;

    public Test()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "one", r.Next(10) },
            { "two", r.Next(10) },
            { "thr", r.Next(10) },
            { "fou", r.Next(10) },
            { "fiv", r.Next(10) }
        };
    }

    protected Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // Here _dict.Count == 0
        // So it found a Dictionary but no content?
        _dict = (Dictionary<string, int>)info.GetValue("foo", typeof(Dictionary<string, int>));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("foo", _dict, typeof(Dictionary<string, int>));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var pair in _dict)
            sb.Append(pair.Key).Append(" : ").Append(pair.Value).AppendLine();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the **main** to test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t1 = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine(t1);
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new FileStream("test.test", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        formatter.Serialize(stream, t1);

    Test t2;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("test.test", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        t2 = (Test)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    Console.WriteLine(t2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output in the console is the same before and after. But as commented in the **Test** class, the overloaded constructor doesn't read any content in the deserialized Dictionary.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug/subtle side effect?

Comment: My problem is not whether it's possible to serialize or not, but how to "take control" of the serialization process if you will (using an implementation of ISerializable), which seems to be failing.

Comment: @OrelEraki: OP is asking about binary serialization and, specifically, about the validity of a deserialized instance. The provided links don't address this particular area.

Comment: @OrelEraki: I did look through the answers. The answers in the second link do not address Dictionary binary serialization as a member of a composite object, which is the essence of  this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IDeserializationCallback` and defers the completion of its de-serialization until the whole graph of objects is read back. You can see how it was actually implemented on [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) :

```
protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)            

{
    //We can't do anything with the keys and values until the entire graph has been deserialized
    //and we have a resonable estimate that GetHashCode is not going to fail.  For the time being,
    //we'll just cache this.  The graph is not valid until OnDeserialization has been called.
    HashHelpers.SerializationInfoTable.Add(this, info);
}
```

To force the completion call `_dict.OnDeserialization()` in your code:

```
protected Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Here _dict.Count == 0
    // So it found a Dictionary but no content?
    _dict = (Dictionary<string, int>)info.GetValue("foo", typeof(Dictionary<string, int>));

    _dict.OnDeserialization(null);

    // Content is restored.
    Console.WriteLine("_dict.Count={0}", _dict.Count);
}
```

PS: `HashSet<T>`, `SortedSet<T>`, `LinkedList<T>` and maybe few other container types exhibit the same behavior

Comment: Great, thanks! It works now. Also thanks for the link, didn't know about.